# How to design a C++ API for binary compatible extensibility

Tags: c++, virtual, binary-compatibility

I am designing an API for a C++ library which will be distributed in a dll / shared object. The library contains polymorhic classes with virtual functions. I am concerned that if I expose these virtual functions on the DLL API, I cut myself from the possibility of extending the same classes with more virtual functions without breaking binary compatibility with applications built for the previous version of the library.

One option would be to use the [PImpl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) idiom to hide all the classes having virtual functions, but that also seem to have it's limitations: this way applications lose the possibility of subclassing the classes of the library and overriding the virtual methods.

How would you design a API class which can be subclassed in an application, without losing the possibility to extend the API with (not abstract) virtual methods in a new version of the dll while staying backward binary compatible?

Update: the target platforms for the library are windows/msvc and linux/gcc.

Comment: Use C# instead. ;-P

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Several months ago I wrote an article called "Binary Compatibility of Shared Libraries Implemented in C++ on GNU/Linux Systems" [[pdf](http://syrcose.ispras.ru/2009/files/02_paper.pdf)].  While concepts are similar on Windows system, I'm sure they're not exactly the same. But having read the article you can get a notion on what's going on at C++ binary level that has anything to do with compatibility.

By the way, GCC application binary interface is summarized in a standard document draft "[Itanium ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html)", so you'll have a formal ground for a coding standard you choose.

Just for a quick example: in GCC you can extend a class with more virtual functions, if no other class inherits it.  Read the article for better set of rules.

But anyway, rules are sometimes way too complex to understand.  So you might be interested in a tool that verifies compatibility of two given versions: [abi-compliance-checker](http://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/) for Linux.

Comment: The host for the PDF file you posted seems to be done. Could you repost it, please?

Comment: @MichałGórny it seems to be back on again, but I've rehosted it [here](http://static.coldattic.info/restricted/science/syrcose09/cppbincomp.pdf) just in case.

Answer (score 11):

There is an interesting article on the KDE knowledge base that describes the do's and don'ts when aiming at binary compatibility when writing a library: [Policies/Binary Compatibility Issues With C++](https://community.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++)

Answer (score 1):

C++ binary compat is generally difficult, even without inheritance.  Look at GCC for example.  In the last 10 years, I'm not sure how many breaking ABI changes they've had.  Then MSVC has a different set of conventions, so linking to that with GCC and vice versa can't be done...  If you compare this to the C world, compiler inter-op seems a bit better there.

If you're on Windows you should look at COM.  As you introduce new functionality you can add interfaces.  Then callers can `QueryInterface()` for the new one to expose that new functionality, and even if you end up changing things a lot, you can either leave the old implementation there or you can write shims for the old interfaces.

Comment: "In the last 10 years, I'm not sure how many breaking ABI changes they've had". Let me tell you how many. **ONE.**  Current ABI is formalized and described in a standard document.

Comment: I know there was a major break between 2.95 and 3.0 (which has been a serious issue on BeOS and Haiku), but I seem to recall another rather major break between 3.2 and 3.3 or thereabouts (which caused a bit of trouble on Gentoo). Is this incorrect?

Comment: Oh, I thought 3.0 was older than 10 years. Yeah, two. One in Jun 2001, with release of 3.0. Since then they worked to produce a good long-living ABI design and adopted it with 3.2 release in Aug 2002. Seven years ago was the last.

Comment: Recommending COM for solving binary compatibility is like recommending cyanide for treating a headache. Both will solve the problem by killing you :)

Comment: @Alek - And yet, each release of Visual C++ introduces an incompatible fork of the C runtime where malloc in one dll then free in another will crash the program, yet COM objects continue to work.  It's helpful to be able to step away from what you may see as misuse and see what the thing offers you in upside.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the problem of subclassing.

Here is your Pimpl:

```
// .h
class Derived
{
public:
  virtual void test1();
  virtual void test2();
private;
  Impl* m_impl;
};

// .cpp
struct Impl: public Base
{
  virtual void test1(); // override Base::test1()
  virtual void test2(); // override Base::test2()

  // data members
};

void Derived::test1() { m_impl->test1(); }
void Derived::test2() { m_impl->test2(); }
```

See ? No problem with overriding the virtual methods of `Base`, you just need to make sure to redeclare them `virtual` in `Derived` so that those deriving from Derived know they may rewrite them too (only if you wish so, which by the way is a great way of providing a `final` for those who lack it), and you may still redefine it for yourself in `Impl` which may even call the `Base` version.

There is no problem with `Pimpl` there.

On the other hand, you lose polymorphism, which may be troublesome. It's up to you to decide whether you want polymorphism or just composition.

Comment: The wrapper class of Pimpl should have non-virtual methods, as in this case it is used exactly to hide the virtual methods of library classes. If virtual methods would be present on the library interface it would make it impossible to extend the library interface in new versions with more virtual methods while keeping binary compat. But if the published inteface is non-virtual, how will clients subclass it? Hence the post.

Comment: Okay, then I understand your point. But it's not really a problem of Pimpl at this point. More a problem about the use of `virtual` methods in the interface.

Comment: "you just need to make sure to redeclare them virtual in Derived so that those deriving from Derived may rewrite them too". No, overridden virtual methods are implicitely virtual, too.

Comment: @Frank: for the compiler they are, for the reader, it's only obvious if they are marked as such (because nobody wants to dig through the includes). I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: I read the cited comment as you suggested that it makes a difference to the compiler, too.

Answer (score -1):

If you expose the PImpl class in a header file, then you can inherit from it. You can still maintain backward portability since the external classes contains a pointer to the PImpl object. Of course if the client code of the library isn't very wise, it could misuse this exposed PImpl object, and ruin the binary backward compatibility. You may add some notes to warn the user in the PImpl's header file.